# Dagger - Missing Bindings error while injecting View Model Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, viewmodel, dagger-2

I am trying to implement plain dagger (not dagger-android). But while injecting `viewModelFactory` it gives missing binding error

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent
```

--- My AppComponent ---

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    SubComponentsModule::class,
    ViewModelFactoryModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {

    /**
     * A {@see [Component.Factory]} that initializes necessary implementations
     */
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(baseActivity : BaseActivity)

    // Save the reference of factories in the app component for creating sub components
    fun mainComponent() : MainComponent.Factory

}
```

--- SubComponents Module ---

```
@Module(
    subcomponents = [
        MainComponent::class
    ]
)
class SubComponentsModule {
}
```

--- Main Component ---

```
@Subcomponent(
    modules = [
        // Main activity necessary modules comes here
    ]
)
interface MainComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create() : MainComponent
    }

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity) // Add main activity to Dagger graph

}
```

And last ViewModelFactory Module and class

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    /**
     * Returns an instance of [ViewModelFactory]
     */
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactoryModule(viewModelFactory : ViewModelFactory) : ViewModelProvider.Factory

}
```

--- View Model Factory ---

```
/**
 * A [ViewModelProvider.Factory] that is injected onto each [ViewModel] by [ViewModelFactory].
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class ViewModelFactory @Inject
constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = viewModels[modelClass]
            ?: viewModels.asIterable().firstOrNull { modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }?.value
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

I can inject App module dependencies and it works normally but when I try to inject ViewModelFactory like

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
```

It gives me error above.

Here is my activity class

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mTest : SharedPreferences

    lateinit var mainComponent: MainComponent

    /**
     * Create component and inject
     */
    override fun inject() {
        // When rotation happens component and its dependencies recreated :(
        mainComponent = (application as MyApp).appComponent.mainComponent().create()
        mainComponent.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        LogUtils.d("TEST -> $mTest")
    }
}
```

With dagger-android it works as expected but I do not understand why it gives error so anyone can help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: \[Dagger/MissingBinding\] Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353281/error-dagger-missingbinding-mapclass-extends-viewmodel-providerviewmode)

Comment: Wow I did not know it. @DrawnRaccoon creating at least one ViewModel did the trick. Can you post it as answer